# how can I upload multiple files at a single browse using jquery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing a web application in which I have create a page for multiple file 
upload on a single browse not one file at a time.

User will be able to select multiple file on click on browse.

If some one have solution for this please welcome

Thanks!

Comment: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Answer (score 9):

For alternative solution, you can using HTML5 multiple-upload,

**HTML**

set attribute **multiple** for your input-file, check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Input.multiple

```
<form id="form-upload">
    <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" multiple>
</form>
```

**JS**

to upload file using juery, you can use form-data : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

```
 $('#upload').bind("change", function(){
    var formData = new FormData($("#form-upload")[0]);
    //loop for add $_FILES["upload"+i] to formData
    for (var i = 0, len = document.getElementById('upload').files.length; i < len; i++) {
        formData.append("upload"+(i+1), document.getElementById('upload').files[i]);
    }

    //send formData to server-side
    $.ajax({
        url : "process_upload.php",
        type : 'post',
        data : formData,
        dataType : 'json',
        async : true,
        processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
        contentType: false,   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
        error : function(request){
            console.log(request.responseText);
        },
        success : function(json){
            //place your code here
        }
    }); 
});
```

**SERVER-SIDE(ex:PHP)**

```
//just print $_FILES
print_r($_FILES);
```

Answer (score 3):

[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) is a very good JQuery Plugin for file upload.

It's very easy to use too. From the docs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg' : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
    'folder'    : '/uploads',
    'auto'      : true
  });
});
```

Then all you need in html is:

```
<input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" />
```

Obviously including the Uploadify scripts too.